# I Can't download phpmyadmin.conf from amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions, phpmyadmin, filezilla

Since i have to change some settings inside "etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf".

i can't download this file using "FileZilla", I also tried sudo nano command in putty , it returns empty. i don't know how to change permission for this file.

I spent more than an hour. Guide me if someone know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 is a computer rental service, not a web hosting service, so you won't be able to connect with FTP (filezilla)   unless *you* run an FTP server on your EC2 instance.

As for editing the file while you're connected through SSH (putty), you need to make sure that you're properly referencing the file you want.  Try running "sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf".  Note the leading "/" on the file path; it's important.

Comment: Tried it many times but failed. I simply restarted the instance and its now working